# Access JWT payload within resource function in Ballerina

Tags: http, jwt, ballerina

I have a Ballerina service secured with JWT authentication.
I need to write a resource function that has the ability to read the JWT payload. What is the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the above solution, we can also get the `jwt` information using the `http:RequestContext`.

```
resource function get data(http:RequestContext ctx) returns error? {
        [jwt:Header, jwt:Payload] jwtInfo = check ctx.getWithType(http:JWT_INFORMATION);
        io:println(jwtInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can write a resource function such that the resource parameter accepts http header. Then we can extract the `jwt` string part from that and generate `jwt` payload using `jwt:decode`. Please check the following code.

```
    isolated resource function get data(@http:Header {name: "Authorization"} string token) returns error? {
        string jwt = regexp:replace(re `Bearer `, token,  "");
        jwt = jwt.trim();
        [jwt:Header, jwt:Payload] [_, payload] = check jwt:decode(jwt);
        io:println(payload);
    }
```